Why does my Jetpack Compose screen recompose every time I click on a button?
I'm currently working on a Jetpack Compose screen in my Android app, and I've noticed that every time I click on a button, the entire screen seems to recompose. This behavior is causing some performance issues, and I'm wondering why it's happening and how I can optimize it.
Why does my Jetpack Compose screen recompose every time I click on a button?
Here's a simplified version of my code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val appContainer = (application as MyApplication).appContainer
        viewModel = MainViewModel(appContainer.repository)
        setContent {
            MyRetrofitApplicationTheme {
                val uiState =
                    viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    viewModel.fetchPost()
                }
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    uiState.value.posts?.let { MyList(it) }
                    Column {
                        Text(text = "My Title")
                        MyButton(uiState.value,viewModel::updateTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun MyList(posts: List<Post>){

        LazyColumn {
            itemsIndexed(posts) { _, item ->
                Text(text = item.body)
            }
        }
    }

@Composable
fun MyButton(uiState: UiState,onclick: ()->(Unit)){
    MyTitle(uiState)
    Button(
        interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue),
        onClick = onclick
    ) {

        Text("click here")
    }
}
class NoRippleInteractionSource : MutableInteractionSource {
    override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()
    override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}
    override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true
}
@Composable
fun MyTitle(uiState: UiState) {
    Text(text = uiState.counter.toString(), modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp))
}



class MainViewModel(private val repository: PostRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState(null))
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    var job1 : Job? =null
     fun fetchPost() {
        job1 = viewModelScope.launch {
            print("call api!!!!")
            delay(2000)
            when (val result = repository.getPosts()) {
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _uiState.update {
                        it.copy(counter = -1)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Success -> _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(posts = result.data)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateTitle(){
        _uiState.update {
            var mcounter = it.counter
            mcounter ++
            it.copy(counter = mcounter)
        }
    }
}

data class UiState(val posts : List<Post>?, val counter : Int = 0)


I tried only copying the value of the counter while updating the UI state, but my LazyList and Button get recomposed every time I click on the "update title" button. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Layout Inspector Screenshot

Because you are updating the uiState value when you click the button and calling updateTitle in your view model

I am updating by copying the value of the counter, isn't that supposed to avoid recomposition on the other parts of the screen?

Please share your UiState class as well

data class UiState(val posts : List?, val counter : Int = 0), also updated on the sample code.
